# Program skips g.fillRect(); on different computers

Tags: java, draw

This is what it looks like when run on another PC (Win8/10) and on my PC(Win7)

[image]

```
if (dy>dx){
        pn = pn+2*dx-dy;
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(jpw2-5+xn*10,jph2-yn*10+5,10,-10);
        System.out.println("xn= "+xn+"   yn= "+ yn);

        while (!(xn==x2 && yn==y2)){


            if (pn<0){
                yn=yn+ys;
                pn=pn+2*dx;
            }else{
                xn=xn+xs;
                yn=yn+ys;
                pn=pn+2*dx-2*dy;
            }
            System.out.println("xn= "+xn+"   yn= "+ yn);
            g.fillRect(jpw2-5+xn*10,jph2-yn*10+5,10,-10);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(jpw2+x1*10,jph2-y1*10,jpw2+xn*10,jph2-yn*10);

    }
```

It skips the g.fillRect(); but doesn't skip g.drawLine();
Works perfectly on my computer and my friends computer both running win7, but doesn't work elsewhere as seen in 1st pic.

Comment: Tested it on another win 7 PC and it works properly.

Comment: Both pictures correctly draw the line between the points shown at the bottom of the image. However, the values of x1,y1,x2,y2 are different in the two pictures. The problem doesn't seem to be that the fillRect() is being skipped, but rather that the points are being computed differently.

Comment: My bad for including different examples in pictures, but no its not the cause of problem. http://imgur.com/IC1xDAH

Comment: It appears to be Windows 10 only issue. Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: UPDATE: I figured it out on my own. g.drawRect(x,y,Width,Height) I had negative value for Height and it basically draws the rectangle flipped upside down, which renders it transparent in Windows 10.